# How to get child view from circular looped horizontal RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to select the list at specific position by default while opening the activity/fragment. By simple I need to get Recycler child view by position.

I tried the following, but it produces null object reference. also tried using handler but no use same issue exists.

```
View view = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position)
recyclerView.findViewHolderforLayoutPosition(position)
reyclerView.findViewHolderforAdaperPosition(position)
```

Comment: It's unclear about what you are trying to do. You should elaborate and enhance your question to have good answers.

Comment: By simple I need to get the child view of recycler view by using adapter position ..is there any way to get this..?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter show selected view by position.

And then use convenience methods to scroll to a certain position:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: I need to get the view of recycler view child item..?

Comment: You can change this view correctly since it is reused. You need always change it in your adapter by position.